# Usage of "of" and "from" after some of verbs

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In my mother tongue we use these prepositions after almost all verbs! But in English sometimes I doubt to use them or not for example after these verbs:

1. Using of my PC or using my PC or etc.
2. Protecting of the environment or protecting the environment

There is a same problem with "with","to" and some others!

I know it is a very basic question but the main problem is the system where I have learned English. I know many English words and can use them properly but there are also many basic problems from many years ago! I can say it is the problem of most educated Iranians even English teachers! I will be glad to hear you about how can I recognize use of them when and where and if there is a rule to guide me or I have to keep in mind all of them? If it seems too broad or extended matter for you please ignore the matter and focus on examples 1 and 2 in the context.

Comment: user37, the question is too broad for having an helpful answer. Preposition usage is a complex matter and there are books with thousand of pages explaining the cases in which is better using one rather than the other. Please, consider to edit the question restricting the field to one example usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the examples *using* and *protecting*: these verbs are directly acting on the noun, so they do not need a preposition between the verb and the noun.

However, for a verb such as *swimming* or *laughing*, you do need a preposition, because a verb like this needs a word to clarify its relationship to the noun to provide meaning. For example,

> "He is swimming with me."
>
> "She is laughing at him."

Answer (score -2):

1. using my PC
2. protecting the environment

Comment: It is not about which of is correct but why is it correct and another form is wrong?